# How to troubleshoot a long delay when connecting over SSH?

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd

SSH'ing to my Linux workstation from my Mac laptop works totally fine, except that there is sometimes a very long delay before I see a prompt. If I try again then it's fast like normal, but a few hours later when I reconnect I see the delay again. This has never happened before a few days ago, and rebooting the workstation doesn't help.

I tried running `ssh -vvv my.host.com` and the delay is here:

```
debug1: pledge: filesystem
debug3: client_repledge: enter
-----> Very long delay here <-----
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: received RSA key SHA256:<snip>
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching /Users/jacobsa/.ssh/known_hosts for <snip> / (none)
```

What might the delay between these lines mean? The fact that the client is just waiting makes me think the slow operation might be on the server side. How can I see logs/traces of what is happening there?

Comment: A common technique is to manually run a secomd instance of the ssh server on an alternative lort (not as a daemon), connect to that and view the server output.

Comment: This would normally point to a DNS problem. You could try seeing if there is a delay after clearing the DNS on the target system.

Comment: Do you  use the `ssh-agent`? This might help.